# PHP - Fatal error: Call to undefined method HTML2FPDF::FPDF() in C:\wamp\...\html2fpdf.php on line 149

Tags: php

I'm getting fatal error:

> Call to undefined method HTML2FPDF::FPDF() in
>   C:\wamp\www\mycourse\html2fpdf\html2fpdf.php on line 149

when try to convert a html file to pdf using `html2fpdf-3.0.2b.zip`.

I'm trying to convert a HTML file (mywebpage.html) into a Pdf file?

This is line 143:

```
$this->FPDF($orientation,$unit,$format);
```

and below is almost the whole function including line 143

```
function HTML2FPDF($orientation='P',$unit='mm',$format='A4')
{
    //! @desc Constructor
    //! @return An object (a class instance)
    //Call parent constructor
    $this->FPDF($orientation,$unit,$format);
    //To make the function Footer() work properly
    $this->AliasNbPages();
    //Enable all tags as default
    $this->DisableTags();
    //Set default display preferences
    $this->DisplayPreferences('');
    //Initialization of the attributes
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',11); // Changeable?(not yet...)
    $this->lineheight = 5; // Related to FontSizePt == 11
    $this->pgwidth = $this->fw - $this->lMargin - $this->rMargin ;
    $this->SetFillColor(255);
    $this->HREF='';
    $this->titulo='';
    $this->oldx=-1;
    $this->oldy=-1;
    $this->B=0;
    $this->U=0;
    $this->I=0;
```

Comment: Are you saying you're trying to use a 12 years old PHP class on a modern version of PHP that probably deprecated the way it autoloads?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I didn't know that. Can you please advise me what class should I use?   I found it [here](https://www.macronimous.com/resources/Converting-HTML2PDF-using-PHP.asp)

Comment: I already added an answer. It's hard to tell how old is the article either as it's not dated (a convenient way of never being old...)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, and yes, this is a very old script, but I was able to solve this same problem today. So, in case someone else comes searching in the future, here is what solved it for me.

Edit the line:

```
//Call parent constructor
$this->FPDF($orientation,$unit,$format);
```

To be:

```
//Call parent constructor
parent::__construct($orientation,$unit,$format);
```

And you should be all set.

For the record, I also changed

```
function HTML2FPDF($orientation='P',$unit='mm',$format='A4')
```

To be

```
function __construct($orientation='P',$unit='mm',$format='A4')
```

In order to match the modern standards.

Answer (score 0):

Your function names don't match you should use the same case sequence

```
 function HTML2FPDF


 html2fpdf
```

if you have function HTML2FPDF(..)    call HTML2FPDF(...)

Comment: Thanks. but in my code it is `$pdf=new HTML2FPDF('','','');`.

Comment: Thanks. Good. worked. Error gone !! But I'm getting an new error **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'assessmenttoolbox' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\mycourse\htmlpdf.php on line 11**  and the line 11 is the file name, found below : `$fp = fopen("assessmenttoolbox.html","r");`

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend using https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf for any serious HTML to PDF conversion. Any other PHP Class that doesn't use the wkhtmltopdf engine has very poor support for CSS and would basically force you to use table design from the 90s to keep the correct layout.

I used wkhtmltopdf extensively a few years ago and it gave me very good results.

I would certainly not use a lib that is, according to this page, 12 years old...
https://sourceforge.net/projects/html2fpdf/files/html2fpdf/

Comment: Thanks. I'm struggling to install it. it needs some kind of Composer !!! I download the latter and install but still can't get it worked. Please can you help !! Their wiki in gitHub doesn't provide details on how to install the composer !!!

Comment: You could also run wkhtmltopdf directly using an `exec()` or `system()` call and play with the command line options. This class just makes it easier to use but is probably not the easiest to setup. I personally always used it using the command line and didn't even bother installing the class

Answer (score 0):

http://pdfcrowd.com/web-html-to-pdf-php/

you cna try this for pdf conversion, it is one of the best html to pdf generator, and the library you are using is 12 years old,